# Visual Studio Macro To Switch Solution Configuration

Tags: visual-studio-2008, macros

I'm trying to write a macro that toggles between release/debug solution configurations in Visual Studio.

It appears I can switch the configuration by using 'DTE.ExecuteCommand("Build.SolutionConfigurations", "Debug")'.

Is there a way I can 'read' the value?  Or is there a way I can use macros to 'focus' on the solution configuration UI element?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hrmm.  Digging made me find this bit of code:

```
    DTE.ExecuteCommand("Build.ConfigurationManager")
```

Which will bring up the configuration manager and allow me to bring up the configuration manager which has the 'configuration' selected so I can switch in a jiffy.

Although looking into it, it looks like that's already key-bindable if I use 'Build.ConfigurationManager', so maybe I don't need the scripts after all.

Anyhow, I'd still like this question answered if possible, so I'll keep it open in case it's useful for someone else.

Answer (score 1):

Here ready macros for that:

```
Sub ConfigurationToggle()
    Dim current As String = DTE.Solution.Projects.Item(1).ConfigurationManager.ActiveConfiguration.ConfigurationName
    If current = "Debug" Then
        DTE.ExecuteCommand("Build.SolutionConfigurations", "Release")
    Else
        DTE.ExecuteCommand("Build.SolutionConfigurations", "Debug")
    End If
End Sub
```